# Why can't I use EdgeWeight in RandomGraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to create a weighted random graph. The random graph is already created

```
g = BlockRandom[
  RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[4, 0.5], DirectedEdges -> True,
    VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

but when I add `EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}, k]]` I don't get nothing, for any `k` I have used

How can I get a `RandomGraph` with weighted edges?

Comment: How does `g` "know" `k`?  Also, check whether weights can be negative...

Answer (score 2):

```
g = BlockRandom[RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[4, 0.5], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeWeight -> {_ :> RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]]
```

[image]

```
{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]} & /@ EdgeList[g]
```

> {{2 -> 1, -0.424925}, {2 -> 3, 0.767566},{3 -> 2, -0.333168},
>   {3 -> 4, 0.385857}, {4 -> 1, 0.323498}, {4 -> 3, 0.610081}}

Comment: Very nice idea with the pattern syntax. There's always something new to discover :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
BlockRandom[
  g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[4, 0.5], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
  g = Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}, EdgeCount[g]]];
];
g
```

?

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome!